# Is there a theoretical explanation for a change of a major7 to minor7 of the same root in jazz?

Tags: theory, chord-progressions, jazz

In jazz there are many chord substitutions with various names like tritone, but there's a particular chord movement which I have seen in many jazz standards where major7 is immediately followed by a minor7 of the same root. For instance in a popular jazz standard Misty there's a part where Abmaj7 is immediately followed by Abm7.

Is there a theoretical explanation to this type of change and when should it be applied?

Comment: Check out [this page](https://www.learnjazzstandards.com/blog/learning-jazz/jazz-theory/how-to-master-the-backdoor-jazz-chord-progression/). You've identified this major-to-minor movement within an extremely common chord progression sometimes called the "backdoor progression." It is all over the place in jazz (Misty, How Deep is the Ocean, My Romance, Stella by Starlight, Just Friends...). The major-to-minor comes in when you backcycle (add V's and ii's to the V's). For example, check out the movement around the circle of 4ths: `|| EbM | Cm | Fm | Bb7 || Bbm | Eb7 | AbM | Abm Db7 || EbM | ...`

Comment: @jdjazz your response should be posted as an answer more than a comment. Kindly expand it and post it as an answer.

Comment: There are a lot of good answers already, and if I were to write a full answer, it would be way too similar to Matt L.'s (who is spot-on, I think). I wanted to include a comment mostly to share the linked article and to provide some context for understanding your question and the answers below. My point about the circle of 4th's isn't an answer to your question--the answer (I think) is Matt L.'s explanation about borrowed chords. I just wanted to highlight the circle of 4th's as something to keep an eye on when looking at the existing answers and thinking about why the progression sounds good.

Comment: @jdjazz thanks for the explanation. As for which response is spot on, I will rather wait until I have heard other possible answers. For instance the comment and the link that you gave provided a much simpler and detailed explanations of the "Backdoor Progression" which is a concept that I wasn't even aware of and none of the answers given here had touched upon.

Comment: Those are good points. So, the reason I prefer Matt L.'s answer is that it explains why | AbMaj | Abmin | EbMaj | works *as well as* | AbMaj | Abmin Db7 | EbMaj |. I see his answer as being somewhat more general, whereas the backdoor progression is maybe a narrower idea. The article does a great job of explaining the resolution, but it focuses on the V7 up a whole step to I resolution (e.g., Db7-EbMaj), which is a little different from the major-to-minor movement you've identified in this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens very often in a major key with the IV chord, which is altered to the minor chord with the same root (iv), and then resolves to the tonic chord. This works so well because of the voice leading. E.g., in C major you would get F to Fm to C, where the note A (third of F) moves down to the Ab (third of Fm) resolving to G (fifth of C).

The iv chord in a major key is often called a [borrowed chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borrowed_chord), because it can be viewed as borrowed from the parallel minor key (i.e., the minor key with the same root). This borrowing is part of a broader concept called *modal interchange*.

In the song Misty, if played in Eb major, the Ab maj7 chord is the IV chord, and the resolution back to Eb maj7 is as described above, just that there's usually a Db7 (bVII) chord in between the Abm7 and the tonic chord. That Db7 has the same function as the iv chord, because it is basically the same as an Abm6 chord, just with a different root.

Comment: Yes, the ⅳ chord has also been discussed in numerous other questions on the site. IMO it acts not so much as a burrowed chord from the parallel minor, but as a neat way of bringing in some tension in form of notes from the strongly dominant ⅶ⁰ chord, without the dissonance of an actual diminished chord.

Comment: This answer is by far the best explanation. Using chords from the parallel minor key is a very common and effective device. It occurs in many other ways, not just on a IV chord, for example on the tonic in several Jobim tunes like Wave and Triste. Other widely used parallel minor chords are the bIII and the bVI. Also I don’t see any correlation between a IVm7 and a VIIo chord.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a chord substitution but could be a cadence or a key change.  As mentioned in other answers a very common device (found in other forms of music not just Jazz) is

IV --> iv --> I (example in the key of C, F --> F min --> C)

The Maj 3rd of the IV chord is the 6th degree of the Key and the movement is chromatic walking down to the 5th degree of the key, the 5th of the I chord.

This is an alternate resolution to the classic IV --> V7 --> I.

If one is changing key down a whole step then this could be a set up for a ii-V-I in the new key.  Changing from C to Bb one might have C --> C min7 --> F7 --> Bb.

Moving away from your example for a moment it is quite common to replace any chord in the circle progression with its dom 7th to move to the next chord in the progression (with the exception of the IV as that moves to the viii).

C --> C7 --> F --> F# dim --> B-7(b5) --> B7 --> E-7 --> E7 --> A-7 --> A7 --> etc

This created the sound and feel of a resolution to the next chord in the sequence.

Comment: +1  I not only agree in principle, but I'd go as far as to say that this is exactly how the "trick" is used in the vast majority of the cases. Tune Up by Miles Davis is a classic example of just that.

Answer (score 3):

This isn’t something that theory ‘commands’ you to do, in the way that a dominant expects to resolve to a tonic.  It's not following some rule.  It’s just a thing you CAN do, and not a particularly ‘outside’ one.  Same root, different flavour of chord.  A unifying factor and a variation.  Happens all the time in music.  Repetition, imitation, variation.

'Misty' is based on two types of stock progression.  There's the ii7 - V7 - I in bars 2-3 then again (aiming for a different temporary tonic but not actually getting there!) in bar 4.   Then there's the standard 'cycle of 5ths' turnaround in 5-6 and 7-8.

ii7 - V7 - I is a very strong progression.  You can jump to almost ANY m7 chord with the flimsiest of excuses and justify doing so by treating it as the beginning of such a progression.   Modifying an existing chord is a pretty conservative way of setting off for somewhere exotic.   'Giant Steps' uses a rather more contrived method!

In the case of 'Misty' I can't see much point in calling it anything more complicated than 'modifying a chord'.   Does 'Modal Interchange' tell you anything extra?

[image]

Here's another direction 'Misty' could have taken.  Still ii7 - V7 - I, which is what gives it integrity with what's before. (I've carried on and 'taken it back home' but I didn't have to.)   Not quite so obvious, which makes it... well what?  'Theory' can tell us it's a less obvious choice, but not that it's a worse one.  (Since when was 'obvious' better?)

[image]

(And I'm sure you've noticed that 'Misty' DOES take very much this route in the middle 8!)

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer but if I understand your argument correctly, then you're saying that the Abm7-Db7 combination might as well have been any other II-V progression. This is really not the case, and there's a good reason that it is Abm7-Db7, and not (for instance) Am7-D7.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there's a chance for an interesting discussion. "Does 'Modal Interchange' tell you anything extra?" Yes. When that Abm7 chord kicks in, to my ears, self-evidently the D note becomes Db automatically, even if the next chord wasn't a Db7.  "Modal interchange" is a more suitable word for describing the change of situation than just saying that one single chord was modified. I mean, nobody would try to solo a strong D natural on the Abm7 chord?

Comment: I didn't downvote you either. Wish you could beef up your answer and land it with a solid theoretical explanation. As it stands now, it sounds more like the Xmaj7 to Xm7 change is just an artistic license.

Comment: Well, like so many musical things it IS just an artistic decision! Theory can describe it, but theory doesn't command or predict it. It COULD have been Am7 - D7. A bit more 'outside', but quite possible. It would have led to a temporary tonic of G or Gm.   See my extended answer above.

Comment: @Matt L. Have you noticed what harmonic route 'Misty' actually DOES take in the middle 8?

Comment: @LaurencePayne I have been noodling around, using my ear and trying this out; _"ii7 - V7 - I is a very strong progression. You can jump to almost ANY m7 chord"_; You are right! I didn't know it but it works outright

Comment: @PhemeloKhetho: Of course a 2-5-1 is a very strong progression, nobody would doubt that. But here it is specifically about a 2-5 resolving to the tonic of the song. And apart from the actual 2-5 (Fm7-Bb7), the only other frequently occurring option is Abm7-Db7, for the reason explained in my answer.

Comment: @LaurencePayne: Yes I have, but this has no bearing on our answers, because nobody would doubt that you can use any II-V to go anywhere at any point in a song. The point is, which IIm7-V7 can be used to lead to the *tonic*? And there are only 2 reasonable choices. In the key of Eb major, Abm7-Db7 is one of them. And there's a good reason why it works, unlike Am7-D7 or most others.

Comment: Yes, "modal interchange" *does* tell us something extra, because it tells us a specific detail of this style. If someone were to come along and try to write something in the style of "Misty," modal interchange may get them there, and just "modifying a chord" likely won't. Imagine you sat down in a writing class and the instructor said "Eh, grammar is just theory. Just put whatever letters you like right next to each other...it's your artistic decision!" That's hardly an answer, don't you think?

Comment: @Richard - isn't 'Modal interchange' just another way of saying 'modifying a chord'?

Comment: @LaurencePayne Modal interchange is a very specific subset of modifying a chord. Which is why this clarity is important: just saying "modifying a chord" opens up possibilities far beyond the realm of mode mixture.

Comment: You can create a modal mixture even with single notes without playing any actual chords. Play notes from “outside” and the harmonic context changes.

Comment: You're still playing chords.  Just linear rather than vertical.

Comment: I upvoted appreciating the point about not forcibly imposing theoretical explanations everywhere. I also think that Tune Up would have made a much better example than Misty in this case.

Comment: @MMazzon the reason why I picked "Misty" over "Tune Up" is because it is more popular and it has been covered a lot by many artists. There are many other jazz standards that I could have used as examples of major to minor change using the same root.

Comment: Laurence, you acknowledged yourself that there's a difference when you wrote "it COULD have been Am7 - D7. *A bit more 'outside', but quite possible*." Why does one sound more outside? Theory can explain why Am-D7 sounds more outside than Abm-Db7--it can explain why Abm-Db7 leads to the tonic in a more natural sounding way. Those explanations are valuable for understanding the genre and creating/working within it. Theory offers the language for distinguishing between the differences you identify in how it sounds.

Comment: @MattL., I agree 100% with everything you and many others have said. RE: ii-V's leading to the tonic, maybe there are 3 if we count Bm-E7-EbΔ.

Answer (score 2):

One place I've seen this done a lot in jazz harmony is in a pair of descending ii-V progressions (often in the bridge). As an example, E♭m7 A♭7 D♭maj7 D♭m7 G♭7 C♭maj7. There's a lot of ways to explain why this 'works', but the key is that the shift is primarily created to get from the first key, D♭ major, to the second, C♭ major. You could also call the whole progression a variation on iii VI ii V I in C♭ major.

The color shift one gets from that parallel transformation is a nice sound, and just as good a reason to use this chord sequence as any other. So most of the time I see that chord movement of major to minor on the same root, it's either the minor plagal sound (IV iv I), or it's the ii V down two semitones thing I explained above.

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the classic sources for the sound is the B section of *Cherokee*..

```
C#m7  F#7   BΔ7   BΔ7
Bm7   E7    AΔ7   AΔ7
Am7   D7    GΔ7   GΔ7
Gm7   C7    Cm7   F7
```

Each of the four bar lines is a basic `ii V I` pattern, but it is *sequenced down a full step four times.*

The transition between each sequence is where the major to minor change happens. Like: `...BΔ7 | Bm7...`

On a *structural level* you could say that major to minor change is just a happy accident and the bigger picture idea is `ii V I` sequenced down by whole step. That's a theoretical explanation for the major to minor change in what is otherwise just a long progression by descending fifths from `C#` to `F`.

This song is supposed to be the one that Charlie Parker woodshedded on to develop his chops, so it seems like an important example to mention, and it happens this way in other songs.

Another common example is using a *borrowed chord*, a chord that comes from the parallel minor key. In `I V IV iv | I` the minor `iv` is "borrowed" from the parallel minor. In that case the theory is the borrowed chord maintains its function. So, both major `IV` and minor `iv` "function" as subdominants and the change of major to minor just adds chromatic color.

I put *borrowed* and *function* in quotes above, because some may prefer to explain the motion as a chromatic passing tone between the sixth and fifth scales degrees. I think that is a fine explanation too, and doesn't contradict the idea there is not a change of function.

*Misty* has this kind of "borrowed" progression, but it uses it in a specific way involving a `bVII` chord which has it's own special name: *the backdoor progression*: `iv bVII I`.

Compare the *Misty* borrowed chord explanation to the *Cherokee* sequential explanation. While the "function" of the two chords is the same in *Misty* in *Cherokee* the function changes. In *Cherokee* when getting to the `BΔ7` the chord is a temporary tonic `I` in the pattern `ii V I` in `C#m7 F#7 BΔ7`, but then when it changes to `Bm7` in the next sequence it becomes the supertonic chord `ii` of `ii V I` in `Bm7 E7 AΔ7`. In that case the two `B` chord not only change from major to minor but the function also changes.

If all this dithering about the use of "function" is a problem, you can look at it more plainly. In *Misty* when you look at the larger picture the opening section is an elaboration of movement between `Eb` and `Bb` (clearly `I` and `V`.) It starts on `Eb` and ends on `Eb`, that's the tonic. Regardless of the terminology used to describe the two major and minor `Ab` chords, one thing is clear: they aren't doing anything that changes the tonic of `Eb`. That's an "A" section *establishing* a tonic. The "B" section of *Cherokee* it totally different. It starts on `C#` and ends on `F`. It keeps moving and moving, transitioning back to `Bb`. It's a bridge *returning* to a tonic. Instead of talking about function we can describe them as two very different structural events.

Answer (score 1):

The Abm7 chord is just doing the old jazz harmony trick, a temporary change between parallel minor and major tonalities. It can also be called a tonic shift of three semitones. Matt L. already gave an introduction to the subject of modal interchange, but to give a different perspective, I'll add a demonstration of what I feel the Abm7 chord is doing:

I think Laurence tries to say that if we take the question literally, the only "theoretical" explanation for why that was used must come from social sciences or psychology or something. Music theory can only describe the phenomena that happen in the harmonic context AFTER someone has decided to want to do that change. *Why* they did it - it was an artistic choice. They liked the feelings produced by the change, or at least they thought that prospective customers might like it. ;)